# json_decode a type of array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

hi guys i am facing a problem in decoding an array from a curl response and assinging value of result to variable.I want to assign the value of `auth_token` from the array give below to a variable in php.

`{
    "status": true,
    "result": {
        "daily_prize_num": 0,
        "daily_prize_amount": 0,
        "monthly_prize_num": 0,
        "monthly_prize_total": 0,
        "daily_chances": 0,
        "monthly_chances": 0,
        "chances_left": 0,
        "user": {
            "phone": "91889888888",
            "country_id": "2",
            "created_at": 1457242503,
            "verified": 0,
            "device_id": "x55769w0ecb4f9k3",
            "device_token": "APA91bF4ETz2QhQZ8JcbB6TQHPdYa6v7TBnEIrjRySftQrjCVuvYs7owqqTgS76cHN6xmGzzA_rkRuOYuXIo5Po0ngOqo0h_NyAORa899WAwmSgiALdXsjo",
            "referral_code": "",
            "referral_code_used": "4hTRSK",
            "auth_token": "8fd3bd001a3bf5a47021924a80ccb0068cf6f7ccaf19b591b8232e0bfd63aa26b4d19ee589d7ab2dd8f07317936aa76b9762446ae6372ea800a6151460baa81a",
            "is_active": 1,
            "id": 88494,
            "is_first_time": true,
            "profile_completed": false
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: I want the code to do that.

Comment: Then either write it, or find someone who can write it for you - Stackoverflow isn't a coding service. If you decide to try to solve this yourself you're welcome to come back with any problems you're facing.

Comment: See question I tried the above code

Comment: There isn't any code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode and access the array:

```
$r = json_decode ($data, true);
$auth = $r ['result']['user']['auth_token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = json_decode('{"status":true,"result":{"daily_prize_num":0,"daily_prize_amount":0,"monthly_prize_num":0,"monthly_prize_total":0,"daily_chances":0,"monthly_chances":0,"chances_left":0,"user":{"phone":"91889888888","country_id":"2","created_at":1457242503,"verified":0,"device_id":"x55769w0ecb4f9k3","device_token":"APA91bF4ETz2QhQZ8JcbB6TQHPdYa6v7TBnEIrjRySftQrjCVuvYs7owqqTgS76cHN6xmGzzA_rkRuOYuXIo5Po0ngOqo0h_NyAORa899WAwmSgiALdXsjo","referral_code":"","referral_code_used":"4hTRSK","auth_token":"8fd3bd001a3bf5a47021924a80ccb0068cf6f7ccaf19b591b8232e0bfd63aa26b4d19ee589d7ab2dd8f07317936aa76b9762446ae6372ea800a6151460baa81a","is_active":1,"id":88494,"is_first_time":true,"profile_completed":false}}}') ;

$token = $var['result'] ['user'] ['auth_token'] ;
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error

Comment: Set the second parameter of json_decode method as true.

Comment: Its not done same prob I echoed $token...it didn't output

Comment: Try print_r($var) for check the decode result.